# Is there any reason fancyBox3 would behave differently with a Windows server (IIS)?

Tags: iis, fancybox-3

A gallery presentation behaves differently when the pages are served from a Windows (IIS) server. The presentation is ordinary, an array of thumbnails organized into a fancyBox3 gallery.

Upon clicking the first thumbnail, fancyBox3 appears and properly displays the image for the clicked thumb. A split second later, the displayed image enlarges.

[image: Incorrectly Upscaled]

Navigating to the next image and then back again displays the first image properly.

[image: Normal]

It is only on the first click that the weird scaling occurs. Thereafter, the gallery works properly.

My code to display these galleries is the same on IIS and Apache servers. The behavior on Apache servers is as expected. I checked using PHP 5.6 and 7.1 and I checked using different browsers. This only happens with IIS.

For reference, the thumbnail is 175px square and for this gallery the full-size images are 600x600px. As can be seen in the first image, the upscaling is much larger than 600x600.

Demo page available at http://www.jordanlally.com/test-files/fb3.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not using jQuery v3.0.x or v3.1.x

Comment: Yes. These versions have API differences that affects width/height calculations.